# Broadcasting a message throgh android clients using Wifi

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I decided to build an android app to implement a chatting mechanism. this mechanism is a bit different of the usual chat systems.

It is not peer to peer messaging system rather we have a message sender and multiple repetitions. every reception after getting the message from source, repeats and resend it to others. the below image shows our broadcasting system:

[image]

in this system every message has an unique id so very client broadcasts the message just once.

i know socket programming and also `UDP` based solutions but in implementation phase the networking foundation is challenge. we don't have any centralized server so every clients should do listen a particular port and resend the given message.

I guess the reception need `UDP` to announce its listening open. also sender lists the its neighbors receptions over `UDP` protocol. then connect with them and sends the message. BUT here we don't have any access point or connectivity among sender and receptions.

Should I use hot spot? I am completely confused.

Please give me help or suggestions to implementing the network.

Comment: This is early/old network communication model, I have seen some project base on this logic but every project fails, this model will never work because of dependences you want to use. So easy to use device operator network communication, why would you complex your life? What is the reason?

Comment: actually my limitation is the WiFi distance range. Imagine two person in a location which there is not any networking system except mobile phone and they are so far (1KM) with each other. if some phone be in between them they will be connected together through the suggested mechanism!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html), it seems to fit your specification.

The Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) APIs allow applications to connect to nearby devices without needing to connect to a network or hotspot (Android's Wi-Fi P2P framework complies with the Wi-Fi Direct™ certification program). Wi-Fi P2P allows your application to quickly find and interact with nearby devices, at a range beyond the capabilities of Bluetooth.